# Does each HTTP request have its Apache environment variables

Tags: apache

I am planning to use the REMOTE_USER  CGI environment variable to get username who is authenticated by Apache basic authentication.  But what I am worries about is if the scope of REMOTE_USER this request or not. Which means each request has its own "REMOTE_USER". If not, there might be an issue caused by race condition I am worried.

Apache version : 2.2

Comment: I believe that not (unless you are using [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), which is a bit out of fashion). See also [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). However, the simplest way is to study the source code of your Apache server. And I am not sure your question makes any sense in the general case.